# Entity Framework 6 throws exception for missing SQL table not required by DbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a DbContext, similar to the one below

```
public class ProductsDB : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
    //..other stuff..
}
```

Here's Product;

```
[Table("product")]
public class Product
{
    [Column("Product_ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //other fields...
}
```

This all works fine until I create a class that inherits from "Product";

```
[Table("CentralProducts")]
public class CentralProduct : Product
{
    //fields...
}
```

When I run integration tests I get an error that states that dbo.CentralProducts doesn't exist. It doesn't, and for the database that ProductsDB is connecting to I don't want it to.

I have tried the various inheritance options but they either require the addition of a table to my database, or the addition of a discriminator column to the Product table.

I had hoped that since my context doesn't consume CentralProducts it would not require it to exist.  I was using [table-per-type inheritance](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) so there shouldn't be any need for something consuming dbo.Product to be able to access dbo.CentralProduct. Is there a way to configure EF6 to allow for this?

The reason I am trying to do this is that I have two databases, each with a common set of tables. I would like to create two DbContexts, one for each database, each containing the core entities but also including a few differences. In this particular case, the second DbContext has a Product table that includes an additional field, hence my attempt at inheritance to solve the problem.

Comment: You may be better off just keeping them separate. While inheritance may seem a neat solution now, you might be introducing unnecessary complexity that is hard to manage later.

Comment: @ste-fu Thanks, that is my current approach. I'm just duplicating the whole Product class and renaming it "CentralProducts" (and adding the additional fields). Its just a shame because any field added to Product will now also have to be added to CentralProduct. It's not the end of the world.

Comment: You might be able to get away with using a `BaseProduct` class, which is the base class for the `Product` and `CentralProduct` classes in different contexts.  But it feels a little dirty to me.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [complex type](https://entityframework.net/complex-type).